# Saving a byte array containing a particular folder structure to a directory in java

Tags: java

I was receiving a byte array which I was storing as zip file using Java, Now I want to unzip the byte array and save it in a directory. If I unzip the byte array, I will get a particular directory structure which I want to store in another directory. Can anyone kindly suggest the best way to do it?

Regards,
Anirban

Comment: If you know how to zip it, you should know how to unzip it ;). Jokes apart, can you show some code?

Comment: That's unclear; do you mean that the byte array is nothing else but the contents of a zip file?

Comment: Yes, the byte array is the contents of a Zip file. What I was doing previously is to store the Zip file in a directory in my computer, then in another method, read the zip file and unzip it. Now I want to directly unzip the byte array and store it in the same location in my PC. I will show some code a couple of days later as I do not have it handy now